# Call javascript function within a PHP form

Tags: javascript, php

The architecture I use to load contents onto a common area on the web page is as below

I have a java script function within the form as shown below called `javaScriptFunc` which never gets invoked.

Is it possible to invoke a java script function within a form?

Please do let me know if more clarity is needed. I'll try to clarify. I'm stuck with this for a while now. I'd appreciate any help please

Comment: Assuming no syntax errors, that function certainly *should* be called.  Are there any errors on the JavaScript console?  What does the resulting JavaScript look like?

Comment: Just to make sure, you're familiar with the difference between where the php is running and where the js is running, correct? One is running on the server, and on in the browser, so its a little confusing to read 'Call javascript function within a PHP form'. Perhaps you could attach an architecture diagram to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, I the `JS` function doesn't seem to fire from within a form. I've worked around by re-writing the `load` logic to load the whole `PHP` page instead of a form. just a different way of doing things.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing some PHP tags if I understand what you are trying to do correctly. Try this:

```
<form method="post" action="" id='somdId'>
<?php
require_once 'some_php_file.php';

if (isLoggedIn()) {

   // Some PHP code here
?>
    <script>
                javaScriptFunc(<?php echo formatJson(someArgs); ?>);
    </script>

    <?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Hello Aaron - Sorry, missing out on the PHP was a typo on my part while drafting the question. Many thanks for spotting it. I've updated the question. It just doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: I would try an alert in your script tag to see if that gets hit. If the alert works then you have narrowed it down that the error lies in javaScriptFunc.

Answer (score 0):

Not very clear what you want. You need to echo the script like this

```
 echo ("<script type='text/javascript'>javaScriptFunc(" . formatJson(someArgs) . ");</script>");
```

provided you have already defined the function javaScriptFunc somewhere else in script.

Comment: The echo is no necessary.  OP has unbalanced `<?php>` tags, so the assumption is that the missing closing tag was snipped with in the `// Some PHP code here` line.

Comment: **Probably.** Without the full code hard to say.  I suggest @usert4jju7 debugs JS with Firebug. Most likely case of a well defined code not called is previous errors in `JS`.